# 'Unresolved variable' about some variable used just one line above (PHPStorm 2018.2.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, ide, ecmascript-5

I'm struggling with my IDE with a simple code. I'm running under Angular 1.4, ES 5.1.

```
function myFunction() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.listResults = null;

    SomeService.someFunction()
        .then(function (result) {
            vm.listResults = result;

            if (vm.listResults.length > 0) {
                vm.selectCity(vm.listResults[0]);
            }
        });
}

vm.selectCity = function (city) {};
```

The last if statement throws a warning and declares the `vm.listResults` variable unresolved. Same for the call to `selectCity` and its parameter. I can't CTRL+CLICK on those three and I don't really understand why.

What do I have to enabled in order to link this properly ?

Under `Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries`  I have `angular-DefinitelyTyped`, `HTML` & `Node.js` Core checked and that's all.

And yes, I could disable the warnings but I'd rather not to, I really want to understand.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: can't recreate using provided code snippet; please share a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue. Note that adding `angular-DefinitelyTyped` to libraries doesn't enable angular support for your project, you need to include `angular.js` file (debug version, non-compressed) in your project

Comment: Adding angular.js file didn't solve the case but the project is kind of a complete library without main entry (just common controllers, directives, services, filters...). Adding the library into its own libraries solved my problem, I never thought about this oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically as I just replied, my project is like a big library commonly used by many of our other projects (common controllers / directives / services / filters...). It doesn't include angularjs in its package.json because this lib is just imported into projects that already load it, so I guess that's why it didn't work.

Adding this same library into its own libraries just solved my problems :)